# mongodb - unwinding nested subdocuments

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

For the following dataset example:

lists

```
{ _id: 1, included_lists: [ 2 ], items: [ "i1" ]}
{ _id: 2, included_lists: [], items: [ "i2", "i3" ]}
```

items

```
{ _id: "i1", details: [{}, {}, {}]}
{ _id: "i2", details: [{}, {}, {}]}
{ _id: "i3", details: [{}, {}, {}]}
```

I want to grab all the items for a list, including the ones attached to the `included_lists`

For example: if we're looking at list `_id` 1, we should get items `i1, i2, i3`

I have an idea how to do this, which involves using `populate` or `$lookup`, but I'm not sure how to unwind the nested `items` inside the `included_lists` and join them with the `items` in the original list.

In the end, I would like to have a dataset where I am able to use `limit`, `skip` and `match`.

I'm using mongoose, but vanilla mongodb code would also be fine.

**Update**

My current idea of how to do this is to retrieve all of the list ids first in one query i.e.

```
List.find({ _id: id}, { included_lists: 1})
```

Then, with the list ids, make an array of that i.e.

```
var all_ids = [id, ...included_lists]
```

Then just find the items and unwind

Psuedo-code:

```
List
    .aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                _id: {
                    $in: all_ids
                }
            }
        },
        { $lookup: {} }
        {
            $unwind: "$items"
        },
        {
            $project: {
                "list.name": 1,
                "list._id": 1,
                "items": 1
            }
        }
    ])
```

But I don't want to have to do a first query to retrieve all the list_ids, I should be able to retrieve all related items just through one `_id` which would then be able to retrieve the rest of the items through `included_lists`

Comment: for `_id` 1 there is only one item `items: [ "i1" ]`?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet it's just an example. Don't think it should really matter whether there's 1 item or 10,000 items. It's just to indicate that it's an array, therefore X amount of items.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation from mongodb 3.6 and above

```
List.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": id }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Items.collection.name,
    "let": { "items": "$items" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$items" ] } } }
    ],
    "as": "items"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Lists.collection.name,
    "let": { "included_lists": "$included_lists", "items": "$items" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$included_lists" ] } } },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": Items.collection.name,
        "let": { "items": "$items" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$items" ] } } }
        ],
        "as": "items"
      }},
      { "$project": { "allItems": { "$concatArrays": [ "$$items", "$items" ]}}}
    ],
    "as": "included_lists"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$included_lists" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$included_lists" }}
])
```

Comment: does this include looking up items in the `included_lists`?

Comment: I would then like to merge to two item lists as one, in order to perform `skip` and `limit` functions. Should I use `mergeObject` after that?

Comment: Cool!!! You can use `$concatArrays` I have updated the answer... Do you want `items` as root document? because now they are nested inside `included_lists`

Comment: Is it possible to also include their originating list `_id` and list `name`? So like doing an `$unwind` with a `$project : { name: 1, item: 1 }`

Comment: I didn't get your point... Can you post how you are getting the data now by updating your question

Comment: I will clarify this answer a little later

Comment: The results aren't correct. It's returning less results than expected. Do you know of any MongoDB fiddle that I could use to better display my issue?

Comment: Yes you can post your document here and share the link

Comment: Not sure how to use it, namely creating a new collection :\

Comment: I think I will ask a new question when I work out a work around (including details on how to setup my test cases) so the results are clearer

Comment: Yes please ask a new question and please post your sample data and the output you want in the question so that it would be easier to give you the perfect answer

Comment: Here's the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51816656/mongodb-aggregating-and-unwinding-foreign-ref-documents I've made the setup commands and my current query and result. It should be good to go, copy-paste, in a mongodb terminal

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation in 3.4.

Initial [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to get the items values for included_lists followed by [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) to merge the looked up items and items.

Second [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to get the item details followed by [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to flatten the results.

```
List.aggregate([
{"$lookup":{
  "from":name of the list collection,
  "localField":"included_lists",
  "foreignField":"_id",
  "as":"included_items"
}},
{"$unwind":"$included_items"},
{"$project":{"allItems":{"$concatArrays":["$items","$included_items.items"]}}},
{"$lookup":{
  "from":name of the item collection,
  "localField":"allItems",
  "foreignField":"_id",
  "as":"lookedup_items"
}},
{"$unwind":"$lookedup_items"},
{"$skip": some number},
{"$limit": some number}
])
```

Comment: this doesn't work, it throws errors, namely referring to the field names

Comment: apologies. syntax errors. fixed and tested now.please adjust the answer to include name of collection and skip & limit values.