# mongodb - aggregating and unwinding foreign ref documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

So for my example database set up:

```
db.lists.insertMany([
    { _id: "1", name: "list1", included_lists: ["2"], items: ["i1"] },
    { _id: "2", name: "list2", included_lists: [], items: ["i2", "i3"] }
])


db.items.insertMany([
    { _id: "i1", name: "item1", details: [{}, {}, {}] },
    { _id: "i2", name: "item2", details: [{}, {}, {}] },
    { _id: "i3", name: "item3", details: [{}, {}, {}] }
])
```

I'm currently getting my items data via:

```
db.lists.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": { "$in": ["1", "2"] } } },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "items",
            "localField": "items",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "item"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$item" },
    {
        "$facet": {
            "results": [
                { "$skip": 0 },
                { "$limit": 10 },
                {
                    "$project": {
                        name: 1,
                        item: 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "total": [
                { "$count": "total" },
            ]
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

which returns:

```
{
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : "1",
            "name" : "list1",
            "item" : {
                "_id" : "i1",
                "name" : "item1",
                "details" : [
                    {

                    },
                    {

                    },
                    {

                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : "2",
            "name" : "list2",
            "item" : {
                "_id" : "i2",
                "name" : "item2",
                "details" : [
                    {

                    },
                    {

                    },
                    {

                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : "2",
            "name" : "list2",
            "item" : {
                "_id" : "i3",
                "name" : "item3",
                "details" : [
                    {

                    },
                    {

                    },
                    {

                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "total" : [
        {
            "total" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'm trying to do, is remove the `{ "$match": { "_id": { "$in": ["1", "2"] } } },` as I want to remove the query needed to get the array of ids, and instead just get all the ids from list `_id` and its `included_lists` ids. Then have return all the `items` return like my result.

This question is similar to: [mongodb - unwinding nested subdocuments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51813872/mongodb-unwinding-nested-subdocuments/51814098?noredirect=1#51814098) but I've reasked due to ambiguity and lack of db documents.

Comment: why do you need the included list if you want to run over all the list documents anyway  ? it sounds like you just don`t wont the match statement

Comment: @AmitWagner I don't want to run all over the list documents. I only want what's in desired list `_id` and anything that's also in `included_lists`. So if I were to target list `"2"`, I would only return 2 results max.

Comment: can you post the expected output as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with graph lookup and then group

```js
db.lists.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": { "$in": ["1"] } } },
    {
      $graphLookup: {
      from: "lists",
      startWith: "$_id" ,
      connectFromField: "included_lists",
      connectToField: "_id",
      as: "connected",
   }
        },
  
    {$unwind:"$connected"},
    { $group:{_id:"$connected._id",items:{$first:'$connected.items'},name:{$first:'$connected.name'}}},
     {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "items",
            "localField": "items",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "item"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$item" },
    {
        "$facet": {
            "results": [
                { "$skip": 0 },
                { "$limit": 10 },
                {
                    "$project": {
                        name: 1,
                        item: 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "total": [
                { "$count": "total" },
            ]
        }
    }
    
    

   
]).pretty()
```

Comment: If I wanted to add a `$match` statement for the unwound `items`, where should I put it?

Comment: Ah, added it after the `$unwind`